Windows OnScreen Keyboard not opening automatically, on tablet
I am developing a kiosk like application, in this mode i have replaced the default windows explorer.exe shell with my application.
While in this mode, the tablet that i have this applied on does not open up the windows onscreen keyboard on clicking on input text fields of external apps.
This works fine while using the app in the normal mode.
I have verified that the reg keys are all set as following:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7\EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke = 1
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7\DisableNewKeyboardExperience = 1
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\TabletMode = 1

These still does not seem to help my case.
